# Paired t test in R is giving me this error :not enough 'x' observations

Tags: r, statistics

I tried using na.rm= True but still the same error .
I run the following snippet on 3 clusters ,but I'm only able to see results of t test only for the first cluster.
A,B are dataframe having the foll columns : ID,columna, columnb, cluster. I want to do paired t test on columna and columnb.

```
for (i in 1:n){
    print (paste ("cluster",i,sep="_"))
    A<-A[A$cluster==i,]
    print(t.test(A$columna,A$columnb,paired=True,na.rm=T))
    B<-B[B$cluster==i,]
    print(t.test(B$columna,B$columnb,paired=True,na.rm=T))}
```

I'm able to get results only for i = 1 cluster and for i = 2 I get not enough x observations etror

Comment: The first assignment in your loop wipes out every element of `A` except where `cluster == 1` on the first time through.  After that, there are no others.

Comment: Oh you mean to say second loop will not remove i = 1 and 3 and keep 2 ?

Comment: One way: `Atmp <- A[A$cluster==i,]`, then `t.test(Atmp...)`.

Comment: I tried this it worked.Is there any other way to write this same code efficiently..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `by` to iterate across all unique clusters, passing subsetted data frames into a user-defined generalized method. The output becomes a list of t-test results.

```
proc_ttest <- function(df) t.test(df$columna, df$columnb, paired=True, na.rm=TRUE)

a_ttest_list <- by(A, A$cluster, proc_ttest)
b_ttest_list <- by(B, B$cluster, proc_ttest)

# RESULTS
a_ttest_list$`1`    # NAME INDEX
b_ttest_list$`1`

a_ttest_list[[2]]   # NUMBER INDEX
a_ttest_list[[2]]
...
```

To return a list of *Cluster_##* names, adjust the cluster column before running `by`:

```
A <- transform(A, cluster = paste0("cluster_", cluster))
a_ttest_list <- by(A, A$cluster, proc_ttest)

a_ttest_list$cluster_1
a_ttest_list$cluster_2
a_ttest_list$cluster_3

B <- transform(B, cluster = paste0("cluster_", cluster))
b_ttest_list <- by(B, B$cluster, proc_ttest)

b_ttest_list$cluster_1
b_ttest_list$cluster_2
b_ttest_list$cluster_3
```